# how to do hedging in global market give the time zone issue

Tags: portfolio-management, quant-trading-strategies, quantitative, order-execution

Hi I am considering a question:
Give you have a global portfolio, consisting of U.S stocks, Euro Stocks or even Japan stocks and you have to rebalance daily according to my calculated trading signals. After the signals are calculated, what should i do to rebalance the whole portfolio by countries according to the time zone or there is any techniques i can avoid it.
What if my signals change during execution?
Thanksss!

Comment: Have you tried back testing your strategy using different arbitrary solutions?